# Objective C: UIAlert in an IBaction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uialertview, ibaction

I would insert an UIAlert in an IBAction when I press a button, how can I do? This UIAlert must show message "Done" and a button to close it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (IBAction)onShowAlertView 
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"done" 
                                                        message:@"" 
                                                       delegate:nil 
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"close" 
                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
```

Comment: Can I enlarge the UIAlert? The UIAlert have standard size?

Comment: It's a standard component, if you want something custom you'll have to write your own.